# How can i use fn as function parameter in other function?

Tags: javascript

How can i use  **fn** as function parameter in other function?
and further more, the **fn** parameter has self parameter. such as `test("b('aa')")`, how to do?

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(fn){
        if(fn){
            fn();
        }
    }

    function a(){
        alert(1);
    }

    function b(x){
        alert(x);
    }

    /* 
        when click I get errors => TypeError: fn is not a function
    */

</script>
```

HTML

```
 <button onclick="test('a')">test('a')</button>
    <button onclick="test('b(hello)')">test('b(hello)')</button>
```

Comment: `fn is not a function` sure, it's a string

Comment: Use `test(a)` instead of `test('a')` for the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(fn,parameter){
        if(fn){
            fn.apply(window,parameter||[]);
        }
    }
    function a(){
        alert(1);
    }

    function b(x){
        alert(x);
    }

    /* 
        when click I get errors => TypeError: fn is not a function
    */

</script>
<button onclick="test(a)">test('a')</button>
<button onclick="test(b,['hello'])">test('b(hello)')</button>
```

Thanks for Felix Kling comment. Here is the explanation.

**NOT** correct, because 'b(hello)' is a string object.

```
test('b("hello")')
```

**NOT** correct, because what you get is actually the return value of b('hello'), which is undefined.

```
test(b('hello'))
```

To send the parameter to function test, you must separate the fn and the parameter.

You can use Function.prototype.apply(***thisValue***, ***argumentsList***).

As what I've written,

```
fn.apply(window,parameter||[])
```

The ***this*** value of fn function is window as default.

`parameter` is the arguments list which is ['hello'] in your `<button>test('b(hello)')</button>` element.
`||[]` prevent undefined variable. `test(a)` is the example that has no argument implemented.

Comment: You should also explain the problem and your solution, not just post code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The post has been amended.

Answer (score 2):

Because 'a' **IS** truthy, but it is not a function. This should work:

`<button onclick="test(a))">test('a')</button>`

Also, your condition in test shouldn't be `if(fn){`, it should be:

`if(typeof fn === 'function'){`

You could execute the b in this manner:

`<button onclick="test(b.bind(null, 'hello'))">test('b(hello)')</button>`

This would pass the `b` function to `test` with 'hello' bound as its first parameter

Comment: Good catch, I am updating my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can proxy arguments without need to change the functions:

```
<button onclick="test(a)" />
<button onclick="test($.proxy(b,window,'hello')" />
```

Or within the function you can test for b's artiy

```
if (x.arity>0){
  x(arguments[1])
}
```

and click by `test(b,'hello');`